# Botón Actualizar en grilla

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-urls

Buenas tardes, le comento necesito hacer una función que en la grilla tenga un botón el cual me permita actualizar un dato de tipo BooleanField, el botón lo tengo aplicado y con un mensaje lo que no se si esta bien realizado para que me realice el cambio como corresponde es la parte del Views ya que no se si me esta realizando la actualización, les dejare el código tanto del html, el views, el forms y el url por si me pueden ayudar a solucionar el problema.

Mi Views del modificar para realizar la anulación:

```
def modificar_boleta(request, id_venta):


    queryset = Venta.object.filter(estado_documento= True).update(estado_documento = False)
    messages.success(request, "Boleta Anulada Correctamente")

    return redirect(to="listar-boletas")
```

El urls que llama al código:

```
path('modificar-boleta/<id_venta>/', modificar_boleta, name="modificar_boleta"),
```

Mi HTML:

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{% block js %}

<script>
    function modificarBoleta(id_proveedor) {
        Swal.fire({
            "title":"¿Estás seguro de anula la Boleta?",
            "text":"Acción Irreversible",
            "icon":"question",
            "showCancelButton": true,
            "cancelButtonText":"Cancelar",
            "confirmButtonText":"Aceptar",
            "confirmButtonColor":"#dc3545"
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            if(result.isConfirmed) {
                window.location.href = "/listar-boletas/"+id_venta+"/"
            }
        })
    }
</script>

{% endblock %} 

{% block contenido %}

{% load humanize %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="card">\
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 align="center">Listar Ventas</h2>
        <hr>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-sm">
            <tr>
                <th>Nro Documento</th>
                <th>Tipo Documento</th>
                <th>Rut Vendedor</th>
                <th>Rut Cliente</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Estado Documento</th>
                <th>Fecha de Creación</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
            </tr>
            {% if object_list %}
            {% for v in object_list %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{v.id_venta | title }}</td>
                <td>{{v.tipodocumento | title }}</td>
                <td>{{v.rut_vendedor | title }}</td>
                <td>{{v.rut_cliente | title }}</td>
                <td>${{v.total | intcomma }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% if v.estado_documento %}
                    Activa
                    {% else %}
                    Anulada
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>{{v.fecha_creacion | title }}</td>
                <td>
                    
                    <a href="#" onclick="modificarBoleta({{ v.id_venta }})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Anular</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>




{% endblock %}
```

El Forms:

```
class VentaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id_venta_inicial = Venta.objects.aggregate(Max('id_venta'))
    id_venta_inicial = id_venta_inicial.get('id_venta__max')
    if id_venta_inicial is None:
        id_venta_inicial = 1
    else:
        id_venta_inicial = id_venta_inicial + 1
    id_venta = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=id_venta_inicial) 
   
    class Meta: 
        model = Venta
        fields = '__all__'
```

Les agradecería un montón que me pudieran ayudar con respecto a este problema.
Que tengan una excelente jornada.